# How to show videos from specific folder in an android activity?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to show all videos from a specific folder in android activity. so when user click on it, video will play maybe on android internal video player or etc. Please help me to achieve my tasks. I am also posting a picture of my desired output. I want list videos just like in the picture.[this is picture of MX-player, i want same functionality in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1vau.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the piece of code given below:

```
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null);
count = videocursor.getCount();
videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
}
private OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position,
long id) {
System.gc();
video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoActivity.this, ViewVideo.class);
intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
startActivity(intent);
}
};

public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context vContext;
public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
vContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
return count;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
System.gc();
TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());
String id = null;
if (convertView == null) {
video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
tv.setText(id);
} 
else
{
tv = (TextView) convertView;
return tv;
}
```

Let me know if you are facing any issue with this, I'll be happy to help you.